# Entity framework change state of parent abstract object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an inheritance relation between for example two tables, the parent is abstract.

The problem is that changing state of instance of Car doesn't affect the parent table.

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public int Version { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

Vehicle x = context.Vehicles.FirstOrDefault();
x.Model = "new value";
context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

I have a trigger should happen when an update operation happen on table Vehicle on the database and the trigger is never executed because the table Vehicle is not updated.

Comment: Can you please post your trigger's content?

Comment: The problem is not with the trigger content, the problem is that the trigger is not executed because the parent table is not updated.

Comment: This is strange. If this is inheritance, the table for `Vehicle` and `Car` is the same.

Comment: In the database they are two tables while in the DbContext the parent is abstract so we only talk to the child.

Comment: I think this is the problem. In standard inheritance, EF uses one table for the two entities. The update process suppose the very same thing.

Comment: Ef supposes that they are one table in .Net but when it moves to the database it communicate with the two tables if values on both of them had changed but in my case i only update a value in one table so it doesn't update the second one. So i have to change the state of the parent table which is already hidden inside the children object. I wish you got what i want to say :)

Comment: I'm the problem, it is working fine now and i still looking for why it wasn't and now it does.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well I took a look to this interesting article

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

and in effect EF Code First manages inheritance classes relation as one single table on the db with a special field called "Discriminator".

At this point, as far as concern what you said in the OP and in comments that are followed, you should put the trigger, on the table with the "discriminator" field and not in an eventually present Vehicle table that is not supported by the EF data layer.

Comment: There are no errors in the code, try it yourself @Ciro Corvino

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something ☺

Comment: Thank you, this will be better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem disappeared and i still don't know why it existed and why disappeared yet, but if it exists again the solution will be :

```
context.Entry(x).Property(x => x.V).IsModified = true;
```